# Mapstruct : map field conditionally or ignore

Tags: java, spring, mapping, mapstruct

I have a class something like this :

```
class StudentDTO {
    String name;
    Integer rollNo;
    List<CourseDTO> coursesTaken;
    Boolean isFailed;
    List<CourseDTO> failedCourses;
}
```

I want to map `failedCourses` List from StudentDTO to Student only if the flag `isFailed` is true, else ignore the field, but without using default implementation in interface. Is there any annotation/paramater in mapstruct that can help me? I've tried using `expression` but can't make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several approaches. But, they all come down writing some custom code to do this:

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper{

   @Mapping( target = "failedCourses", ignore = true )
   Student map(StudentDTO dto);


   List<Course> map(List<CourseDTO> courses);

   @AfterMapping
   default void map(StudentDTO dto, @MappingTarget Student target) {
       if (dto.isFailed() ) {
           target.setFailedCourses( map( dto.getFailedCourses() );
       }
   }
}
```

You could also make a dedicated mapping for one property and use the entire source as input.. Like this

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper{

   @Mapping( target = "failedCourses", source = "dto" )
   Student map(StudentDTO dto);

   List<Course> map(List<CourseDTO> courses);

   default List<Course> map(StudentDTO dto) {
       if (dto.isFailed() ) {
           return map( dto.courses );
       }
   }
}
```